# How to get total of a rows value in a asp.net mvc table

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to show total in a new row in a table. How to write a for loop and show grand total in the next row?

Datatype - consumption is `double`

```
<tbody>
@if (ViewBag.Total_PowerList != null)
{
    Double value = 0;

    foreach (var item in ViewBag.Total_PowerList as List<TransformerEnergyMonitoring.Models.KWHConsumption>)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@item.timeStamp</td>
            <td>@item.finalState</td>
            <td>@item.consuption.ToString("0.00")</td>
        </tr>
    }

    foreach (var item in ViewBag.Total_PowerList as List<TransformerEnergyMonitoring.Models.KWHConsumption>)
    {
        value =  item.consuption++;
    }
    <tr>
        <td>@value</td>
    </tr>
}
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using Viewbag use Model reference in view and use

`<td>@Model.Sum(i => i.consuption)</td>`

If you are using viewbag then write the sum of consuption code done in controller side only and assign that sum of value in different viewbag and use it in view directly.